# XMLReader: Find out, how many bytes have been read

Tags: php, xmlreader

How do I find out how many bytes of a stream have been read, when using XMLReader?

```
$reader = new XMLReader();
$reader->open($uri);

while ($reader->read()) {
    printf("%u Bytes read", ?);
}

$reader->close();
```

Comment: you can use curl_getinfo($uri, CURLINFO_CONTENT_LENGTH_DOWNLOAD); to get size of file

Comment: @JulyanoFelipe I already know the total content length. However, I need the processed content length at any given time.

Comment: I guess it is not possible